# Случайное число в golang

Tags: golang

Как получить случайное число? 
Вот функция, но она выводить всегда цифру "81"

```
package main

import ("fmt"; "math/rand")

func main() {
    fmt.Println(rand.Intn(100))
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Генератор случайных чисел обычно нужно рандомизировать перед использованием, иначе, он, действительно, будет выдавать одну и ту же последовательность.

В `golang` это можно сделать вот так:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Seed

P.S. Оставлю тут ещё ссылку на англоязычную версию SO, с вопросом, как правильно инициализировать рандомайзер: [golang random number generator how to seed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321133/golang-random-number-generator-how-to-seed-properly)

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно псевдослучайное число к которому нет требований по воспроизводимости, то можно воспользоваться модулем `math/rand`.

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
```

Если нужен генератор **случайных** чисел, которое будет невоспроизводимо (к примеру, *для шифрования/криптографии*) - стоит воспользоватся `crypto/rand`, который [использует API системы](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#pkg-variables) для получения псевдослучайного числа

```
import (
    "math/big"
    "crypto/rand"
)

r, err := rand.Int(rand.Reader, big.NewInt(80))
```

Comment: Вместо .Unix() мне больше нравится использовать .UnixNano(), так как в противном случае в течение одной секунды генератор будет выдавать одни и те же «случайные» числа.

Answer (score 1):

Эта функция должна выводить случайное целое число в диапазоне от 0 до 99. Но если она всегда выводит "81", то, скорее всего, проблема в том, что вы не инициализируете генератор случайных чисел. Вы можете сделать это с помощью следующей строки кода:

```
rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
```

Добавьте эту строку перед вызовом `rand.Intn(100)`, и ваша функция должна начать выводить случайные числа.

Обратите внимание, что данный код будет работать только в том случае, если вы импортируете пакет `time`:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)
```

`rand.Intn(n)` возвращает случайное целое число в диапазоне от `0 до n-1`. Это значит, что вызов `rand.Intn(100)` вернет случайное целое число в диапазоне от `0 до 99`. Если вы хотите получить случайное число в другом диапазоне, например, от `1 до 100`, вы можете использовать следующую формулу:

```
rand.Intn(100) + 1
```

Обратите внимание, что функция `rand.Intn` использует генератор псевдослучайных чисел, который выдает числа, которые выглядят случайными, но на самом деле являются предсказуемыми. Если вам нужно более случайное число, вы можете использовать функцию rand.Int63n, которая возвращает случайное целое число типа `int64` в диапазоне от `0 до n-1`. Например:

```
rand.Int63n(100)
```

Есть еще несколько функций, которые могут быть полезны в работе со случайными числами в Go:

1. `rand.Float64` возвращает случайное число типа `float64` в диапазоне от `0.0 до 1.0`.
2. `rand.NormFloat64` возвращает случайное число типа `float64`, распределенное нормально (гауссово распределение) со средним значением 0.0 и стандартным отклонением 1.0.
3. `rand.Perm` возвращает случайную перестановку диапазона целых чисел `[0, n)`. Например, `rand.Perm(5)` может вернуть `[3, 1, 4, 0, 2]`.

Важно помнить, что перед использованием функций из пакета `math/rand` нужно инициализировать генератор случайных чисел с помощью `rand.Seed`, как я уже упоминал ранее. Это необходимо, чтобы генератор мог выдавать реально случайные числа, а не всегда один и тот же набор чисел.

Функция `rand.Intn` использует генератор псевдослучайных чисел, который реализован в пакете `math/rand`. Этот генератор состоит из алгоритма, который вычисляет следующее случайное число на основе предыдущего числа. Это называется линейным конгруэнтным генератором (LCG).

Линейный конгруэнтный генератор использует следующую формулу для вычисления следующего случайного числа:

```
next = (current * a + c) % m
```

Здесь `current` - текущее случайное число, `a, c, m` - константы, которые определяют свойства генератора. Чтобы получить случайное число в диапазоне от `0 до n-1`, мы просто вычисляем `next % n`.

В пакете `math/rand` для реализации линейного конгруэнтного генератора используются следующие значения констант:

```
a = 1103515245
c = 12345
m = 2^32
```

Каждый раз, когда вы вызываете функцию `rand.Intn`, она вычисляет следующее случайное число с помощью линейного конгруэнтного генератора и возвращает `next % n`. Это означает, что функция всегда возвращает целое число в диапазоне от `0 до n-1`.

Например, если вы вызовете `rand.Intn(10)`, то функция вернет случайное целое число в диапазоне от 0 до 9. Если вы вызовете `rand.Intn(100)`, то функция вернет случайное целое число в диапазоне от 0 до 99. И так далее.

Если вам нужно получить случайное число в другом диапазоне, например, от 1 до 100, вы можете использовать следующую формулу:

```
rand.Intn(100) + 1
```

Это добавит 1 к результату `rand.Intn(100)`, так что результат будет находиться в диапазоне от 1 до 100.

Answer (score -2):

Решение:

```
package main

import ("fmt"; "math/rand"; "time")

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    var bytes int
    bytes = rand.Intn(100)
    fmt.Println(bytes)
}
```

Comment: Вы бы лучше отметили галочкой ответ с решением, на котором основывались. Ничего нового по теме вопроса этот ответ не добавляет. (PS: минус не мой, но, вероятно, за это)